# Polylang strings does not show some plugin

Tags: php, string, woocommerce, translate, polylang

I am using WordPress, polylang, woo-commerce, woo poly integration plugin.

I want to translate woo commerce tab title at another language product page.
but it does not show on strings of polylang. strings only show 5 plugins to edit and it does not include the woocommerce plugin.

please teach me how can I add manually to change language or 
what should I do to change?

Comment: You can try to use custom script to change language of your tab name manually.